# What principled arguments are made with data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, philosophical, history, fiducial

Consider the frequentist argument: "I will believe A since not-A makes the data improbable".
Consider the Bayesian argument: "I will believe A since given my beliefs on A and the data generating process, it is more probable than not-A".

Are there any other argument types and how would you construct an argument? (Fiducial? Fuzzy logic? Dempster-Shafer? Possibility theory? Bounds? ...)

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can make one that doesn't use hypothesis tests (or any statements about A and NOT A) at all. Something like:

> We had evidence of a relationship between A and B because of (cite
>   literature) but we thought that this needed further exploration
>   because (give reasons). When we did (cite analysis done) we found
>   (cite relationship found) which (strengthens/weakens/alters) our
>   notion of the relationship. Reasons for this are (give more reasons)

Comment: Thank you Peter. I agree this does qualify as a data driven argument. I guess I had a more quantitative approach in mind.